How can I make compilation errors in Github PRs more prominent?
I have a large (~100 developers), NX-managed Typescript repo, with github actions running on pull requests. The action workflow runs many steps, of which the main step compiles the code by basically running yarn run nx affected --target=build. All works well.
However, if the PR has a compilation error, it's quite difficult for the developers to find the error. They need to:

Look in the PR page, see that the check ("CI / main") failed, and click details
See the build page. It shows lots of steps, with the step "build (main agent only)" marked as failed (see screenshot below)
Expand that step, at which point they get a 1700-line log, ending with an unhelpful Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
Search this log for Error: - only now do you see the actual compilation error (see screenshot below).

Many of developers get lost along the way, especially at step 4 (search for Error:), and need assistance. Developer guidance can only go so far...
Question: Is there anything I can do in my workflow to make the errors more discoverable? I vaguely remember that in Azure Devops you could...



But if you enabled distributed caching in your workspace, then a developer should be able to run the same command, and see a distinct error...

Yes, the developer can run the same command locally and get the same compilation error, regardless of NX cache. However, it's yet another step I'm trying to avoid here.

You can use the gh command to add comments to the pull request directly.
Example action file:
on:
    pull_request

jobs:
    ci_build:
        ...
        steps:
            - name: Build code
              run: |
                (build command) 2>&1 | tee build.log
            
            - name: Report failures
              if: failure()
              env:
                GH_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}
                PR_ID = ${{ github.event.pull_request.number }}
              run: |
                tail -n 50 build.log > build_tail.log
                gh pr comment ${PR_ID} --body-file build_tail.log
                

Here the build command is modified to put all log messages into build.log in addition to the normal output (which goes to GitHub action results).
The later step only runs on failure, and takes last 50 lines from the log. The gh pr comment command is used to post a comment to the pull request. The GH_TOKEN is needed for access to the GitHub API, and PR_ID is taken from the triggering event to identify which pull request the build is related to.

Cool, didn't realize that! Although I'm not sure tail -n 50 is the right thing here, since it will just show the unhelpful Error: Process completed with exit code 1. Maybe grep Error: would be better - will need to try that.

Yeah, details will depend on your build process. It may also make sense to only put 2 (stderr) to the log file, instead of all messages. You can use -A and -B options with grep to get some context around the error line.
